# How To Stream Video File Cross Browser On Same URL

Tags: python, django, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am trying to make Video Streaming Application, I have a controller which can stream mp4 video which is not working with Firefox.

```
def get(self, request):

        filename = 'uploads/SampleVideo_1080x720_1mb.mp4' # Select your file here.
        wrapper = FileWrapper(file(filename))
        response = StreamingHttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='video/ogg; multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
        response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(filename)

        return response
```

if anyone can guide me to make it for different browsers ll be appreciated.

actually i want to send stream encoding according to browser or client. dynamically. i am new in python.

which technique is used by Youtube : how youtube serves videos on blob:https%3A//www.youtube.com/456e268f-bdfe-4ce7-8368-6b646a3ec5e8 what is **blob:**